# node.js socket.io php session whit out redis and memcached

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, session, socket.io

I have a site that is delivered by PHP and every user has a Session stored in a php file when he is logged in.

My Question is: it is possible, without redis or memcached, to get the session from the php file to the node.js server or if not, how can I do it with redis an memcached?

Comment: "every user has a Session stored in a php file"... Can you elaborate on that a bit?  You're writing your own session handler?  And you're writing PHP files?

Answer (score 0):

No matter how you store your PHP sessions, if you want to share data with an outside application, it should be served up from your PHP application.  This gives you the flexibility of changing your session handling later on, while avoiding writing some custom session data parsing code on your Node.js application.

```
<?php
session_id($_GET['sessionId']);
echo json_encode($_SESSION);
```

Then in your Node.js application, you can fetch `/getSessionData.php?sessionId=0123456789abcdef` or whatever.  Note that you **must** lock this script down so that it is completely inaccessible except from your other applications.  Otherwise, you would be opening yourself up to a nasty security hole.  Also, if you aren't already rotating session IDs, you should re-write your session handler anyway so that it is hard to re-play requests with an old session ID.